# Rotating towards a final rotation challenge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

Consider this working script, that handles a FPS camera movement:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraHandler : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    float dragSpeed = 10f;
    float lookAtSensitivity = 200f;
    float xRot;
    Transform parentGO;

    private void Start() {
        parentGO = transform.parent;
    }
    void goToPivot(Transform pivot) {
        parentGO.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pivot.position, 0.05f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, pivot.rotation, 0.05f);
    }

    void resetCamRot() {
        xRot = 0;
        float yRot = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
        parentGO.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, yRot, 0);
        transform.localEulerAngles -= new Vector3(0, yRot, 0);
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1)) {  
            float touchX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookAtSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            float touchY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookAtSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            xRot -= touchY;
            xRot = Mathf.Clamp(xRot, -90f, 90f);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, 0f, 0f);
            parentGO.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * touchX);
            
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
            goToPivot(target);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) {
            resetCamRot();
        }
    }
}
```

Check how the rotations take place in different gameobjects in their respective axis, so that each of rotations are kept independent and everything works.

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, 0f, 0f); //camera GO only rotates in local x
parentGO.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * touchX); //parent GO only rotates in global y
```

Problem comes when I need to "force" the camera look a certain direction without the inputs, to the FPS movement rules break, and for example the camera gameobject rotates also in the Y xis. That is why I need to call the `resetCamRot()` method, and traspass the local rotation from the camera object to the parent so that the situation meets the the FPS movement requirements (no local Y axis rotation).

Without calling the `resetCamRot()` method, when the FPS movement starts on right mouse button click, the camera abruptly changes to the direction it was facing before "forcing" it with `goToPivot` that sets the position and the rotation.(Just commentinf the `resetCamRot` method out)

Although `resetCamRot()` does the work it feels a bit hacky, so is there another way to set the camera to a forced rotation maintaining the local rotation of the child object (where the camera is) to 0?

I thought of decomposing the next step rotation given by `Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, pivot.rotation, 0.05f);` in the `goToPivot()` method in each of their respective axis and gameObjects as its done when the rotation is set from the input, to have a clean local Y rot in he camera gameobject each step. Seems to be the over-complicated thing in this case, but was not able to figure that out.

I you wish to try the script out for the challenge just need to add a parent gameobject to the camera and the attach the target in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make the camera look in the direction, the parent transform look in the direction, only flattened, and finally update the internal state (`xRot`) in accordance with the difference between the two:

```
    void LookTowards(Vector3 direction) {
        Vector3 flattened = direction;
        flattened.y = 0f;

        parentGo.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(flattened);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        xRot = Vector3.SignedAngle(flattened, direction, parentGo.right);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll give it a try

Comment: @rustyBucketBay have you given it a try yet?

Comment: That makes the same that I was doing in a more elegant way I think, that is to apply the rotation wiht the FPS rules mentioned. To add the proggresive rotation I was using in the example I just added `Vector3 nextDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, target.forward, Mathf.PI/360, 1);` and then called your method with the `nextDir` argument. That worked and made sense, thanks a lot!